# AWS EventBridge Input transformation rule with array List

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-event-bridge

I have a event with an Arraylist :

```html
I have an Arraylist :

"TelephoneDetails": {
    "Telephone": [
     {
       "Number": "<Number>",
        "Type": "<Type>",
        "Primary": "<Primary>",
       "TextEnabled": "<TextEnabled>"
     },{
        "Number": "<Number>",
        "Type": "<Type>",
        "Primary": "<Primary>",
        "TextEnabled": "<TextEnabled>"
     }
    ]
}
```

how to write the InputTransformer for the InputPath for this ? ,

i can get the Telephone[0]using this

```html
{

  "Type": "$.detail.payload.TelephoneDetails.Telephone[0].Type",
  "Number": "$.detail.payload.TelephoneDetails.Telephone[0].Number",
  "Primary": "$.detail.payload.TelephoneDetails.Telephone[0].Primary",
  "TextEnabled": "$.detail.payload.TelephoneDetails.Telephone[0].TextEnabled"

}
```

not understanding how to write, if I have ArrayList of N?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can't do this with plain EB syntax. Probably the best way would be to put a **lambda function** as target of your EB rule, make the transformations and then forward it to your target.

Comment: Thanks, That’s the last option which I can think of, Checking if there is any way I can achieve this in EB script by using some special characters or syntax.

Comment: @Anitha How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin that's wrong. Actually is there a way, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is simple as that:

```
"TextEnabled": "$.detail.payload.TelephoneDetails.Telephone[*].TextEnabled"
```

please note the `[*]` instead of `[0]` to let the template engine iterates over the list of *Telephones*

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Using `[*]` instead of `[0]` results in the following error:

`Output can not be generated, because field "$.detail.payload.TelephoneDetails.Telephone[*].TextEnabled" can not be found in the sample event`